# CollectionView iOS 7 issue

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview

I have a problem in my collectionView ,In iOS 6 the project works perfectly but when I change the deployment target to iOS 7 , the project doesn't work anymore.

```
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: (<NSIndexPath: 0x8daa110> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil (<CustomCollecionCell: 0x8dab520; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 300 190); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x8daad00>>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x029405e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01de88b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02940448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x017bbfee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x00f5bd81 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 698
    5   UIKit                               0x00f6f19f __51-[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate]_block_invoke1144 + 521
    6   UIKit                               0x00f6c793 -[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate] + 2901
    7   UIKit                               0x00f6ff9c -[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:] + 1635
    8   UIKit                               0x00f6b978 -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations] + 14317
    9   UIKit                               0x00f67f95 -[UICollectionView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:] + 361
    10  UIKit                               0x00f67fdc -[UICollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:] + 48
    11  Home Automation                     0x0004d541 -[MainDashboardViewController stopDragging:] + 6209
    12  Home Automation                     0x00049117 -[MainDashboardViewController handlePanning:] + 215
    13  UIKit                               0x00cc1e8c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
    14  UIKit                               0x00cc0b00 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
    15  UIKit                               0x00cc256d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    16  UIKit                               0x00cc5acd ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
    17  UIKit                               0x00cc5a4e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    18  UIKit                               0x00cbc148 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
    19  UIKit                               0x0098819a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    20  UIKit                               0x009890ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    21  UIKit                               0x0095ce86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    22  UIKit                               0x0094718f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x028c983f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x028c91cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x028e629e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x028e5ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x028e58db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x032d69e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x032d6809 GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x00949d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    31  Home Automation                     0x0000295d main + 141
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x02534725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
```

Note: I have two collectionViews with different customCell classes.

Comment: Please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and any other relevant code.

Comment: though this log doesn't give much of a detail. I believe there is something wrong with your indexPath or data source from which you are creating your collection view.
Concentrate on `[UICollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:] + 48`

Answer (score 3):

From iOS 7 on you are required to register a nib/class for each collectionviewcell you use and calling the dequeue method in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

implemented by your UICollectionViewDataSource.

So first call one of the following methods one time (e.g. in viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

and subsequently use

```
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

to instantiate the actual cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath.